# Mr. M receive $10$ messages on New Years Eve on average. Determine the probability that he receives $3$ messages at most on the next New Years Eve.

Tags: probability-theory

> Mr. M receive $10$ messages on New Years Eve on average. Determine the probability that he receives $3$ messages at most on the next New Years Eve.

So, "on average" should mean that $E(X) = 10$, with $X$ being a random variable that counts the number of messages Mr. M received by $n$ persons who could potentially send him such a message. It might be useful to define

$$X = X_1 \ + \ ... \ + X_n$$

with $X_k := 1$, if the $k$-th person sends Mr. M a message, $0$ otherwise. Then, each $X_k$ is Bernoulli distributed.

All in all, we are looking for the probability that

$$P(X \le 3).$$

Since each $X_k$ is Bernoulli distributed, $X$ itself is Binomial Distributed, hence,

$$P(X \le 3) = \sum_{k = 0}^3 {n \choose k} p^k q^n{n - k}$$

with $p$ being the probability that a person sends him a message. But I cannot see how to determine $p$ with the help of the information that $E(X) = 10$.

Comment: Some information is missing. For instance, if Mr M receives 10 messages every year the answer is 0. But if he receives 0 messages with probability $2/3$ and 30 messages with probability $1/3$ the answer is $2/3$. So we need to know more than the expected number of messages in order to answer the question.

Comment: That's all the information I can give you. It's an old exam question, so it should definitely work somehow.

Comment: My examples above should convince you that the question cannot be answered without further information: the two cases that I described satisfy the assumption but deliver different results.

Comment: In binomial distribution shouldn't it be $P(X \le 3) = \sum_{k = 0}^3 {n \choose k} p^k q^{n - k}$ ?

Comment: True. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Oliv Assume Poisson distribution.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel why?

Comment: @Oliv It's the _standard_ distribution used when talking about independent events that happen in a time series, such as the letter receiving here.

Comment: So the solution would be to use the Markov inequality?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel there is no time series. All messages are sent on the same day. If the senders' decisions to send a message were i.i.d. random variables we could use a binomial distribution for the number of messages but this is an additional (and arbitrary) assumption.

Comment: @Borol Markov inequality delivers a bound, not a value. If you are willing to assume a binomial distribution (notice that this is an extra assumption) you can use $E (X_1+...X_n)=n p=10$. But even then you need to assume a value for either the number of potential senders $n$ or the probability per sender $p$ to derive your result.

Comment: I really don't see the reason for downvoting me here. I was asking a question about an excercise that seemed odd to me too, it's not like I formulated it wrongly.

Comment: A fellow student of mine also told me that this should work with the poisson distribution.

Comment: @Oliv: Could you explain to me in detail why you think that this can't be Poisson-distributed? Then I could ask my professor for it.

Comment: @Borol Did you read my comments? I am not saying that this *can't* be Poisson-distributed, I am just saying that this *doesn't have to* be Poisson-distributed. There are many distributions consistent with the hypothesis that $E(X_1+...X_n)=10$ and the Poisson is just an arbitrary one. Also, as for the binomial distribution, you cannot answer the question unless you make an extra assumption on $n$ or $p$.

Comment: I did read them and for me, it sounded like you would argue against the advice of Parcly Taxel to treat this case as it was poisson-distributed. I tried the poisson-distribution-thing be the way, and it does give reasonable results, so I believe this is what my professor was up to here.

Comment: @Borol so if you are happy with this solution you should include the assumption of a Poisson distribution in your question and answer your own question with your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is reasonable to suppose that the number of people who could potentially send him a message is quite large, and the probability to do it for any person is quite small. Binomial distribution in this case can be approximated by Poisson. Remind that the Poisson distribution serves as the limiting distribution of the number of rare events in the large series of independent trials. Here is just the case.  $\lambda=np=10$ and 
$$
P(X\leq 3)=e^{-10}\left(1+10+\frac{10^2}{2!}+\frac{10^3}{3!}\right).$$